# Self Learning -- Number Theory

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, self-learning

I was wondering if there were any good online courses/lecture videos (preferably courses/videos but books would work too) for self learning algebraic number theory. I have seen sites like MIT OpenCourseWare, but their number theory courses seem to be lacking. So if anyone had any other sites that have courses on number theory or even just a youtube playlist that would be great!

Comment: you can try https://www.math.upenn.edu/~ted/frames.html - choose a course and go to "Current homework and lecture schedule" to get links to video lectures

Comment: What is your background?  Have you studied any number theory before?  Have you studied commutative algebra or topology?

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/54430/video-lectures-of-mathematics-courses-available-online-for-free/54471#54471

Comment: How about "An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers" by Hardy and Wright.

Comment: I'm not an expert,but I found these to be good notes:Prof Robert Ash has a good introduction to the subject, there's also thes good notes by Prof Milne, both can be found on their homepages.also u need to mention your background, for example, have u taken a course on commutative Algebra?Number theory? I think most course on Alg number theory assumes CA, Galois theory, topology... as  prerequisites,

Answer (score 1):

there are some good videos, you can check [(1)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ccpl3GXMy38) or these small playliste [(2)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Be1rZOb9BDk). Good luck